# Returning a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, sapply

I am using the following code to extract the number of complete cases from files:

```
complete <- function(directory, id=1:332) {
    sapply(id, fn, directory)}


fn <- function(id, directory) {
    zero <- sprintf("%03d", id)
    name <- paste(directory,"/",zero,".csv",sep="")
    frame <- read.csv(name)
    ok <- complete.cases(frame)
    return(c("nobs"=sum(ok),"id"=id)) }
```

Then, e.g.:

```
complete("specdata",1:12)
```

This code returns:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12]
nobs  117 1041  243  474  402  228  442  192  275   148   443    96
id      1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10    11    12
```

However, I would like it to return a data frame of the type:

[image]

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Thank you!

Comment: If you put `browser()` inside your function call, you will be able to explore the inner workings of (your) function in real time. See some debugging topics here on SO.

Comment: This is a flagrant violation of Coursera policy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sapply` is returning a `matrix` here. You can get the shape and type you want with:

```
as.data.frame(t(complete("specdata",1:12)))
```

Or put this in the `complete` function, around the call to `sapply`. `t` transposes the `matrix` rows into columns, and `as.data.frame` coerces it into such.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is OK. In order to get your desired result use

```
t(sapply(id, fun, directory))
```

instead of `sapply(id, fun, directory)`.

Your code should look like this;

```
complete <- function(directory, id=1:332) {
    t(sapply(id, fn, directory))}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
complete <- function(directory, id = 1:332) {

 as.data.frame(t(sapply(id, fn, directory)))




}

fn <- function(id, directory){
if(is.numeric(id)){                                                         
id=id
}else{
id = as.numeric(id)
}
fileName  <- paste(paste(directory,'/',sep=''),paste(id,'.csv',sep=''),sep='')
data  <- read.csv(fileName )
tows <- (complete.cases(data))
rowsNum <- nrow(data[tows,])
return(c("id"=as.numeric(id),"nobs"=rowsNum))

}
```